# Uploading ID3 tags with MP3 file to Google Drive - iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I'm currently able to upload MP3 files to Google Drive using the iOS SDK, however I've ran into a problem where I'm unable to combine the ID3 tags within the file. Is there a way to add this information directly into the GTLDriveFile, or at least some alternative?

Current code:

```
GTLDriveParentReference *parentRef = [GTLDriveParentReference object];
parentRef.identifier = self.kDriveMusicDirID;
parentRef.isRoot = NO;

GTLDriveFileThumbnail *thumbnail = [[GTLDriveFileThumbnail alloc] init];
thumbnail.image = GTLEncodeWebSafeBase64(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(file.image, 80));
thumbnail.mimeType = @"image/jpeg";

GTLDriveFile *driveFile = [[GTLDriveFile alloc] init];
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@.mp3", file.artist,    file.songTitle];
driveFile.title = title;
driveFile.mimeType = @"audio/mp3";
driveFile.parents = @[parentRef];
driveFile.thumbnail = thumbnail;

AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:file.assetURL];
[self extractDataForAsset:songAsset withCallback:^(NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
if (error == nil)
{
GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters =
[GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data
                                     MIMEType:driveFile.mimeType];

GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:driveFile
                                                   uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

[self.driveService executeQuery:query
              completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error)
   {
   if (error == nil)
   {
     completion(nil);
   }
   else
   {
     completion(error);
   }
 }];
}
else
{
  //handle the error. notification that the upload has failed.
}
}];
```

Comment: ID3 tags, could u explain what does it mean ?

Comment: ID3 tags are embedded in an MP3 file that would hold the information regarding Artist, Song, Album, Genre etc.
When you import an MP3 track into a music player such as iTunes, the ID3 tags are used to add details into the software automatically. Without ID3 tags, every time you imported a track into a music player, you would have to manually enter details for the artist, song name etc.

Comment: could u show ur code for uploading mp3 files to g drive

Comment: please check my answer. Else show ur code so we can suggest you

Comment: I've added the code to show what I'm working with so far. As you can see, I'm trying to add all information to the GTLDriveFile, so that I'm able to upload it using the Google Drive iOS SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive allows us to upload files in Simple upload, Multipart upload and Resumable upload. If you have metadata that you want to send along with the data to upload, you can make a single **multipart/related request**.

To use multipart upload, make a POST or PUT request to the method's /upload URI and add the query parameter `uploadType=multipart`,

for example:

POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart

For more details Please refer [HERE](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads)

Comment: It's not metadata as such, at least as Google Drive and their APIs are concerned. I was looking at combining the information tags (ID3 tags) in the MP3 file, when I uploaded it to Google Drive. It seems however that it is not possible, as the audio file on the iOS Device has to be converted to NSData format, then sent to Google Drive this way, which unfortunately seems to strip out the ID3 tags automatically.

Comment: @AndyShephard i have given u link, there it shows, how can u upload multipart parameters ....

Comment: while I thank you for the help you have given me, the answer is not really aimed towards the iOS client libraries and therefore, I'm unable to utilise such code. However, while Google Drive would technically allow me to upload files with ID3 tags, the problem I'm having is down to the iOS system, not allowing easy extraction of MP3 files to remote sources. The only solution is to strip the ID3 tags out and convert the audio track to NSData, before uploading it to a remote source.